# Be confused with argument in c++ function?

Tags: c++, c, declaration

What is the difference between 2 fucntions?

```
//a

template <typename T, int N>
int g( T (&a)[ N ] )
{
    return N;
}

//b    

template <typename T, int N>
int g( T &a[ N ] )
{
    return N;
}
```

It is ok to compile the code //a, but for //b I get an error: "`declaration of 'a' as array of references`".
Can anyone explain this error more clearly to me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the syntax for some types are weird because of which such confusion often arises.

- `T (&a)[N]` is *a reference* to an array of T of size `N`, which is allowed by the language, hence the first code compiles.
- `T &a[N]` is *an array* of references (to `T`) of size `N` which is NOT allowed by the language, hence it doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you. But I want to ask 1 more question.
//c
void f(int &a);

So function f is in situation which is similar to //a or //b? Is it a? (that's what I think)
Thanks :)

Comment: @user3425082: `int &a` declares `a` as reference to an int which is allowed by the language.

Comment: So, in conclusion, I can make a reference to a single object not an array of it?

Comment: @user3425082: No. You can make reference to an array (of non-reference) also. But you cannot make an array of references.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. Sorry about my terrible english >"<. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) means that the indexing `[]` comes before the reference `&`. In the first case, you are making a reference to an array with `N` objects of type `T`, whereas in the second case, you have an array with `N` references to objects of type `T`, which is not valid.